# rails redirect_to with & in the params fix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, redirect, url-encoding

I have & in one of my params:
redirect action:

```
format.html {redirect_to :action => 'index',:flag => params[:flag], :tip_type => params[:tip_type], :tip_topic_name => params[:tip_topic_name]}
```

output:

```
Started GET "/admin/answer_reviews?flag=tip_filter&tip_topic_name=Flu+&+Cold&tip_type=Haiku" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-08 13:53:38 +0530
Processing by Admin::AnswerReviewsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"flag"=>"tip_filter", "tip_topic_name"=>"Flu ", " Cold"=>nil, "tip_type"=>"Haiku"}
```

but i want it to be:

```
Parameters: {"flag"=>"tip_filter", "tip_topic_name"=>"Flu & Cold", "tip_type"=>"Haiku"}
```

i have also tried:

```
format.html {redirect_to :action => 'index',:flag => params[:flag], :tip_type => Rack::Utils.escape(params[:tip_type]), :tip_topic_name => Rack::Utils.escape(params[:tip_topic_name])}
```

but it leads to:

```
Started GET "/admin/answer_reviews?flag=tip_filter&tip_topic_name=Flu+%2526+Cold&tip_type=Do%2527s+And+Don%2527ts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-08 14:01:37 +0530
Processing by Admin::AnswerReviewsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"flag"=>"tip_filter", "tip_topic_name"=>"Flu %26 Cold", "tip_type"=>"Do%27s And Don%27ts"}
```

i can gsub '&' with '$' before redirect and then again '$' with '&' in the redirected action , but there must be some less hacky way available ?

Comment: Try, `:tip_topic_name => params[:tip_topic_name].html_safe`

Comment: Yes, but there is problem with html_safe. Don’t use this method unless you’re sure your string isn't nil. Instead use the raw() method, which won't raise an exception on nil.

Comment: Weird.  I assumed the content building helpers automagically URIescaped everything.

Comment: html_safe didnt do what was expected out of it :(
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/answer_reviews?flag=tip_filter&tip_topic_name=Headaches+%26+Migraine&tip_type=Haiku
Completed 302 Found in 3745ms


Started GET "/admin/answer_reviews?flag=tip_filter&tip_topic_name=Headaches+&+Migraine&tip_type=Haiku" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-08 14:41:59 +0530
  Processing by Admin::AnswerReviewsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"flag"=>"tip_filter", "tip_topic_name"=>"Headaches ", " Migraine"=>nil, "tip_type"=>"Haiku"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with this:

```
:tip_topic_name => raw(params[:tip_topic_name])
```

**EDIT:**

After getting feed back, and my comments below, I think you should go with your approach

```
format.html {redirect_to :action => 'index',:flag => params[:flag], :tip_type => Rack::Utils.escape(params[:tip_type]), :tip_topic_name => Rack::Utils.escape(params[:tip_topic_name])}
```

And then to parse string `"Flu %26 Cold"` when it is returning to controller with html_safe, but check if it is not nul before that

you could do that in before_filter , for example, only for index page

**Edit 2:**

What about unescapeing string when parameters are returned. It wouldn't be so hacky.

```
Rack::Utils.unescape
```

Comment: what do we require for raw (NoMethodError (undefined method `raw')?
but most probably it wont work either bcz  the redirect action is working fine Redirected to admin/answer_reviews?flag=tip_filter&tip_topic_name=Headaches+%26+Migraine&tip_type=Haiku but "GET" is what causing the problem: GET "/admin/answer_reviews?flag=tip_filter&tip_topic_name=Headaches+&+Migraine&tip_type=Haiku" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-08 14:41:59 +0530
  Processing by Admin::AnswerReviewsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"flag"=>"tip_filter", "tip_topic_name"=>"Headaches ", " Migraine"=>nil, "tip_type"=>"Haiku"}

Comment: hm, yes. The difference is with "Headaches+%26+Migraine" and "Headaches+&+Migraine". Now when I think using & in url shouldn't e done, as it is special character to tell apart each parameter, and that is why you get nil for Migraine as it is not equal to anything. So I think you should give up from approach to show in :params that special character -> & and to go with %26 and to parse it on return

Comment: yes +1 to Rack::Utils.escape on redirect and Rack::Utils.unescape in the redirected action.works and comparatively very less hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a good practice to use a get request instead of post but as per the requirements that you have there is just a hack way to get escape the special characters as follows:

```
require 'uri'
tip_topic_name= URI.escape(tip_topic_name)
url = "http://myurl.com/#{tip_topic_name}"
result = open(url).read
```

Also check the [docs](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/uri/1.9.2/URI/Escape%3aescape) that have escape representation.

Comment: This doesn't have to do anything with sending a list of parameters. You are sending only one parameter. Also, your are opening an url inside controller - soo NOT rails way

Comment: no, this is a hack way to do pass escape characters meaning to suit it you need to do some changes the way you are doing it like from controller to ruby file to get the result.